# Why are ebextensions are getting ignored

Tags: laravel, devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running into a problem with laravel & Elastic Beanstalk.
I want to deploy a laravel project to aws eb and have setup some vpc and other stuff.

So in my `laravel-app` folder I've created an `.ebextensions` folder and two config files `01setup.config` and `03deploy.config`

My `setup.config` looks like this:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
    document_root: /public
    composer_options: --no-dev --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    APP_ENV: production
    APP_KEY: CATZ
    DB_HOST: CATZ
    DB_DATABASE: CATZ
    DB_USERNAME: CATZ
```

Nothing too fancy here, only setting the document root and composer options. Because the deploy always fails because of laravel dusk. (It's throwing an expection, that its not save to use it in production)

Then I run once

`eb init`

And then

`eb create --vpc.id CATS--vpc.elbpublic --vpc.elbsubnets CATS --vpc.ec2subnets CATZ --vpc.securitygroups CATZ`

To create the eb and set the vpc for the ec and elb instances.

However the deploy fails, because of the laravel dusk package. Digging into the logs, shows that someohow `eb` is not taking up the `options_settings` and the `composer_options` are empty.

I checked the console dashboard under `Configuration - Software - Modify` and the document root nor the env variables are set.

So somehow the `.ebextensions` folder and the config files seems to be ignored.

I've also terminated and re-created the stack, but with the same result.

Comment: If your directory is version-controlled, `eb` will use HEAD to create a zip file. Is .ebextensions/ in VC?

Comment: Thanks @progfan !
Yep the directory was version controlled. And .ebextension were not commited.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your directory is version-controlled, `eb create`/`eb deploy` will use `HEAD` to create a zip file from. Is `.ebextensions/` in VC? If not, you need to commit it.

Alternatively, you can also deploy staged (`git add`-ed) changes rather than committed ones by executing `eb create/deploy --staged`.